# How may I catch and log all exceptions in Rails view (.erb file)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need a way to catch and log exceptions from Rails views.

Strangly enough, a method in the controller does not get exception, if it happens inside <% %> erb block

Comment: This is not expected rails behaviour. Could you update your ticket with a little more information, please? Which version of rails are you using? What do you see on your view when the erb tag has thrown an error? What does the server log look like for that method load?

Comment: The exception goes to the user. I want to catch it, as I easely do with the exception in a controller method.

Comment: The contents of erb tags is ruby, you can catch it in the exact same way. As a standard, it's much better to fix your error instead of trying to recover from it, especially in views which style guides say should have minimal ruby code and known objects passed from the controller. Try to do your error handling somewhere else before running views.

Comment: I do all necessary error catching, but I want to be sure that user does not get an exception by my mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I decided, that the most reliable way is to add a rescue block INSIDE any erb file:

```
<% begin %>

... ERB file here: html, html, some scripts, HTML

<% rescue => e%>
    <% Mylogger.ErrorERB 'Exception in erb:', e %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Is this still the correct way to do this in 2022?